# How to restrict shared folders coming from a Windows XP computer throughout the LAN?

Tags: networking, security, lan

My friend has a problem. He wants to share certain folders only with certain people through LAN. We already tried using the Security tab on the folder to allow only X user from Y computer to access it but the other computer isn't being detected.

What other things should we try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not running Active directory, every person on the LAN has to be a user on the computer with the shared folders. It should work if you add them as users and set a password for them. Do not add them  as administrators because then they could change the permissions set on them.